# Matlab Transfer function not functioning?

Tags: matlab

I'm designing a MTALAB GUI to calculate transfer functions

```matlab
R1 = app.EditField.Value;
R2 = app.EditField_2.Value;
L = app.EditField_3.Value;
C = app.EditField_4.Value;

A=tf([R1*C*L, (R1*R2*C)+L, R2],1);
B=tf([R2*C, R1*C1, 1], 1);
S=A/B
bode(S);
```

However, I keep on getting this error:

```
Error using tf
Invalid syntax for the "tf" command. Type "help tf" for more information.

Error in TEST/EditFieldValueChanged (line 36)
            A=tf([R1*C*L, (R1*R2*C)+L, R2],1);
```

I tried different codes and different functions.

How do I use the `tf` function correctly

Comment: I presume you've done as the error told you, namely call `help tf` and read the documentation that pops up? You've written something that MATLAB cannot use as inputs to `tf()`, hence the syntax error.

Comment: Do you have the Control Systems Toolbox installed? Do you have a different function `tf` that is shadowing the one in the Control Systems Toolbox?